# MaterializeCSS select box open programmatically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, materialize

How do we get the MaterializeCSS select box to open programmatically?

Comment: That's all? No code? No attempt?

Answer (score 0):

/* Please try this solution, this will work */

```
<div class="input-field col s12">
    <select id="mycustomselect">
      <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
      <option value="1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="2">Option 2</option>
      <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    </select>
    <label>Materialize Select</label>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#mycustomselect").click();
    });
</script>
```